# Make SOAP call with HttpClient using OAuth 1.0 c#

Tags: c#, .net, soap, httpclient

Im trying to make a SOAP call with httpClient. The SOAP has OAuth 1.0 Authorization. I dont want to use WSDL provided because its absurdly big.
I have tried to do everything, the call works with Postman, credential are 100% correct, the signature generating code is also correct, because all that works fine when Im calling using WSDL provided, but every time I get "USER ERROR", "Invalid Login Attempt".
To summarize is there way to make a SOAP call with httpClient using OAuth 1.0.

p.s. I also tried RestSharps RestClient, got same thing.
My project is Windows Application (.NET Framework 4.7.2) which is calling a Class Library (.NET Standard 2.0).
Here's the code

```
            content = @"<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
    xmlns:platformCore='urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'
    xmlns:platformMsgs='urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'>
     <soapenv:Header>
        <tokenPassport xsi:type='platformCore:TokenPassport'>
            <account xsi:type='xsd:string'>{{account}}</account>
            <consumerKey xsi:type='xsd:string'>{{consumerKey}}</consumerKey>
            <token xsi:type='xsd:string'>{{tokenId}}</token>
            <nonce xsi:type='xsd:string'>{{nonce}}</nonce>
            <timestamp xsi:type='xsd:long'>{{timestamp}}</timestamp>
            <signature algorithm='HMAC_SHA256' xsi:type='platformCore:TokenPassportSignature'>{{signature}}</signature> 
        </tokenPassport>
      </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <get xsi:type='platformMsgs:GetRequest'>
            <baseRef xsi:type='platformCore:RecordRef' internalId='449' type='customer'/>
        </get>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(content);
            HttpResponseMessage response;

            HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "get");
            //req.Headers.Add("Cookie", "NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING");


            req.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            req.Content = httpContent;
            req.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/xml; charset=utf-8");

            response = client.SendAsync(req).Result;
            var responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: What does it matter how big the wsdl is? The point is that you generate a proxy client and you don't need to bother with the implementation details.

Comment: @Crowcoder If I wont find another way of doing it I will have to use WSDL, I just want to know all my options.

Comment: You can do it without a wsdl and proxy client. But without seeing the wsdl and your code all I can say is what you already know - you are doing something wrong. You could use Fiddler to compare the the network traffic with what you are doing vs. what Postman is doing and then make changes as necessary.

Comment: I have compared them both with Fiddler and they are identical, I can post my code, but not sure where to put wsdl.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.